# What is the most efficient way to format UTF-8 strings in java?

Tags: java, formatting, utf-8, uri

I am doing the following:

```
String url = String.format(WEBSERVICE_WITH_CITYSTATE, cityName, stateName);
String urlUtf8 = new String(url.getBytes(), "UTF8");
Log.d(TAG, "URL: [" + urlUtf8 + "]");
Reader reader = WebService.queryApi(url);
```

The output that I am looking for is essentially to get the city name with blanks (e.g., "`Overland Park`") to be formatted as `Overland%20Park`.

Is it this the best way?

Comment: best way? efficient way?
Do you want performance, or do you want code-readability/maintainability?
I think Recurse's answer probably serves both.

Comment: I had two design points in mind: (1) readability (in my opinion translates to maintainability) and (2) not allocating, moving temp data more than necessary.  I agree and I am using the URLEncoder on the parameters and formatting the String URL with those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are actually wanting to encode your string for use in a URL (ie, "Overland Park" can also be formatted as "Overland+Park") you want `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")`. Other unsafe characters will be converted to the %xx format you are asking for.

Comment: Yup!  Thanks for the correction.  I changed over to the URLEncoder class.

Comment: you can edit your own question/answer (or anyone's question/answer when you have 2000 rep) on SO.  I replaced the single quote by double quotes in your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to use `URLEncoder.encode(...)` as stated by @Recurse.  However, if part or all of the URL has already been encoded, then this can lead to double encoding.  For example:

```
http://foo.com/pages/Hello%20There
```

or

```
http://foo.com/query?keyword=what%3f
```

Another concern with `URLEncoder.encode(...)` is that it doesn't understand that certain characters should be escaped in some contexts and not others.  So for example, a '?' in a query parameter should be escaped, but the '?' that marks the start of the "query part" should not be escaped.

I think that safer way to add missing escapes would be the following:

```
String safeURI = new URI(url).toASCIIString();
```

However, I haven't tested this ...

Comment: I encountered the problem as you stated.  What I chose to do was to only encode the parameter portion and format those results into the URL string.  My problem isn't general purpose -- the service is very specific, but I did want to apply best practices and not move data around any more than necessary.